# CSS Drop out menu not responding

Tags: html, css

So I've really been trying to figure this out. Im trying to make a button box that is fixed on the side of the site its on. I get the button, and the html seems to work but it does not respond when the mouse hovers over. Alternatively I could manage with a button that needs to be clicked. Here's the CSS and HTML I'm using. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```css
/* SLIDING BLOCKS */

.pull-item {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20000;
  transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  width: 304px;
}
.pull-item.top.right {
  top: 160px;
  right: -304px;
}
.pull-item.middle.right {
  top: 150px;
  right: -304px;
}
.pull-item.bottom.right {
  top: 270px;
  right: -304px;
}
.pull-item:hover {
  z-index: 20100;
}
.pull-item.right .pull_butoon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -50px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.pull_butoon img {
  max-width: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
}
.pull-item.right .top-level-pull-out {
  padding: 12px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
  width: 280px;
}
.pull-inner {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}
.pull-inner p {
  margin: 0;
}
.pull-inner img {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.pull-item.left.active {
  left: 0px !important;
}
.pull-item.right.active {
  right: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="pull-item middle right" style="width:374px;right:-374px">
  <div class="top-level-pull-out style=" width:350px ">
            <div class="pull-inner ">
             <div>
              <h4>Place any HTML here</h4>
              <p>&nbsp;
    
        <img src="http://wpdemo.bigonetheme.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/responsive_web_design.png " alt=" ">
        Phasellus euismod tortor ante, et accumsan velit consectetur vitae. Donec dignissim faucibus libero nec luctus. Suspendisse eu tortor mi. Suspendisse dictum justo felis. Pellentesque egestas vel urna nec facilisis. Sed dictum bibendum lobortis. Curabitur vehicula.</p>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="pull_butoon ">
                 <img width="50 " height="50 " src="http://wpdemo.bigonetheme.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/icon_heart-50x501-50x50.png " class="attachment-bio-icon " alt="icon_heart-50x50 ">       </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Your code has a number of problems such as missing quote marks. I suggest you run it though a validator and try to make your question more clear.

Comment: I count one missing quote mark (that clearly is not the issue here), and isn't SO exactly the place for broken code ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps: http://jsfiddle.net/ctj3ykzd/

You where using an `.active` class to style the hover state of the button. This is fine if you are going to add this class via Javascript somehow, but if you want to go with pure css, you have to use the `:hover` pseudo class.

So that is exactly what I did, I replaced `.active` with `:hover` (and I fixed that missing quote in your markup)

Comment: That did it, thanks SO much, have been trying for hours now :)